# Got File not found error after nginx server block configuration

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx server block with the same configuration i used on another server which worked well on the other server but for some reason i couldn't find out can not work on the new server am trying to configure it. below if the config file

```
 server {
    set $project_root /var/www/test.example.com/html;     

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;
    root $project_root;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$args&request_filename=$1 last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }
   
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$args&request_filename=$1 break;
    }
    
    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    
    location ~ .*\.(uploads|img|images)?$ {
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|flv|mp4|ico|svg|woff2|ttf)$ {
      expires 30d;
      access_log off;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(js|css|plugins|assets)?$ {
      expires 7d;
      access_log off;
    }
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.ht|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md) {
      deny all;
    }


    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.ht|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md) {
      deny all;
    }
  }
```

and the error from test.example.com.error

```
errorlog
2020/10/02 14:07:20 [error] 6493#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while readin
g response header from upstream, client: 214.64.240.229, server: test.example.com, request: "GET / H
TTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "test.dajubet.com"
2020/10/02 14:08:09 [error] 6493#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while readin
g response header from upstream, client: 214.64.240.229, server: test.example.com, request: "GET / H
TTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "test.example.com"
```

any help on how to fix this would be appreciated

Comment: Does the file `/var/www/test.example.com/html/index.php` exist?

Comment: @ Richard Smith  yes i have index.php in the directory

Comment: Is `SCRIPT_FILENAME` set in the `fastcgi.conf` file?

Comment: @Richard Smith yes it's set and if i access my server with IP i'm able to browse all files including php file in /usr/share/nginx/html directory with no error but this error occur upon setting up server block and access with domain name